# PHP free time blocks from start and end dates

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, datetime, multidimensional-array

I attempted to get these free time blocks purely from a MySQL query, but I was not able to construct a query that worked with the data that have. I have opted to simply get the `start` and `end` dates from the query and work out the free time blocks in PHP. However this is also proving difficult.

I have the following array (Just an example, days and times will vary):

```
$meeting = array(array('start' => '2016-11-14 16:00:00',
                       'end'   => '2016-11-14 16:30:00'
                      ),
                 array('start' => '2016-11-14 16:45:00',
                       'end'   => '2016-11-14 20:00:00'
                      ),
                 array('start' => '2016-11-14 14:00:00',
                       'end'   => '2016-11-14 15:00:00'
                      ),
                 array('start' => '2016-11-14 13:00:00',
                       'end'   => '2016-11-14 14:00:00'
                      ),
                 array('start' => '2016-11-11 15:20:00',
                       'end'   => '2016-11-11 16:00:00'
                      ),
                 array('start' => '2016-11-11 14:00:00',
                       'end'   => '2016-11-11 15:00:00'
                      ),
                 array('start' => '2016-11-07 07:00:00',
                       'end'   => '2016-11-09 15:00:00'
                      )
               );
```

What I would like to end up with is an array of days with start and end times for each free time block on that day, only between 09:00 and 17:00 on each day, excluding weekends. So for example, the meeting times array above should produce the following array of free time:

```
$daily_free = array('2016-11-09' => array(array('free_start' => '15:00:00',
                                                'free_end'   => '17:00:00'
                                               )
                                         ),
                    '2016-11-10' => array(array('free_start' => '09:00:00',
                                                'free_end'   => '17:00:00'
                                               )
                                         ),
                    '2016-11-11' => array(array('free_start' => '09:00:00',
                                                'free_end'   => '14:00:00'
                                               ),
                                          array('free_start' => '15:00:00',
                                                'free_end'   => '15:20:00'
                                               ),
                                          array('free_start' => '16:00:00',
                                                'free_end'   => '17:00:00'
                                               )
                                         ),
                    '2016-11-14' => array(array('free_start' => '09:00:00',
                                                'free_end'   => '13:00:00'
                                               ),
                                          array('free_start' => '15:00:00',
                                                'free_end'   => '16:00:00'
                                               ),
                                          array('free_start' => '16:30:00',
                                                'free_end'   => '16:45:00'
                                               )
                                         )
                   );
```

As you can see only days with any free time appear in the array, the 7th and 8th of November have no free time so they do not appear at all. Also, the 12th and 13th of November do not appear in the free time array, this is because they fall on the weekend. However, if the 12th and 13th were not weekends, they should appear in the free time array as full days of free time (09:00 to 17:00).

One of the only ways I can think to achieve this is to create an array of each day, and within it have an array of 5 minute increments from 09:00 to 17:00 with a NULL value. Then loop through this array checking if each date and 5 minute increment is within the start and end time in the first array, and mark it as busy if it is. I can then loop through again and get the start and end times of the null values on each day? This doesn't seem like a great solution, and also fails if a meeting is less than minutes.

I don't think I can see the wood for trees at this point, and may be over thinking it.

Is there another solution?

**EDIT:** 
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32ea42) for anyone who wants to try via SQL

Comment: Wouldn't it be simple to create a table with list of days and do the job in SQL? If you create an example dataset on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/), I could show how to do that.

Comment: @AlexBlex SQL Fiddle added to the question, thanks!

Comment: btw what happens with the days without appointments? like 12 and 13? they should be free time as well but you don't include them on your desired output.

Comment: @phobia82 That's a very good point! If they are not on the weekend, they need to be included. I'll edit my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They way I would work through it would be to try thinking of the problem like you are carving something out of a material. I'd start with a day full of free time [09 - 17] then loop over the appointments. For every appointment you are either splitting the existing free time (then re-ordering by start date) or changing the range. It's a lot easier if the times don't overlap. If the appointment is outside of the free time range you can ignore it.

```
{----}  {--------} Free Time Range
           [---]   Appointment in the middle - you need to split

{----}  {--------} Free Time Range
        [---]      Appointment at the beginning - change the start date

{----}  {--------} Free Time Range
             [---] Appointment at the end - change the end date

{----}  {--------} Free Time Range
        [--------] Appointment fills the whole spot - delete
```

Comment: I like this logic a lot! Also welcome back to StackOverflow! looks like you have been gone a while :)

Comment: Consider the appointments starting or ending outside your range, and those ones that takes more than 1 day, like the 7th to 9th you have on the sample

Comment: For multi day, I would have something else that would split that into multiple appointments and deal with it in the same way.

Answer (score 3):

Following the logic by @guided1 I started running some tests, going further and further that I ended writing the whole algorithm, here it is. Please the credits to @guided1

```
$meeting = array(array('start' => '2016-11-14 16:00:00',
                       'end'   => '2016-11-14 16:30:00'
                      ),
                 array('start' => '2016-11-14 16:45:00',
                       'end'   => '2016-11-14 20:00:00'
                      ),
                 array('start' => '2016-11-14 14:00:00',
                       'end'   => '2016-11-14 15:00:00'
                      ),
                 array('start' => '2016-11-14 13:00:00',
                       'end'   => '2016-11-14 14:00:00'
                      ),
                 array('start' => '2016-11-11 15:20:00',
                       'end'   => '2016-11-11 16:00:00'
                      ),
                 array('start' => '2016-11-11 14:00:00',
                       'end'   => '2016-11-11 15:00:00'
                      ),
                 array('start' => '2016-11-07 07:00:00',
                       'end'   => '2016-11-09 15:00:00'
                      )
               );
$min = "09:00:00";
$max = "17:00:00";
$start = "2030-01-01 00:00:00";
$end = "2000-01-01 00:00:00";
$free = [['start' => "2000-01-01 00:00:00", 'end' => "2030-01-01 00:00:00"]];
foreach($meeting as $m){
    foreach($free as $k=>$f){
        if($m['start']>$f['start'] && $m['start']<=$f['end']){
            $free[$k]['end'] = $m['start'];
            if($m['end']<$f['end'])
                $free[] = ['start'=>$m['end'], 'end'=>$f['end']];
        }
        elseif($m['end']<$f['end'] && $m['end']>$f['start']){
            $free[$k]['start'] = $m['end'];
        }
    }
    $start = min($start,$m['start']);
    $end = max($end,$m['end']);
}
$begin = new DateTime( $start );
$end = new DateTime( $end );

$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

$daily_free = [];
foreach ( $period as $dt ){
    $m = [
        'start'=>date('Y-m-d ',strtotime($dt->format('Y-m-d').' -1 day')).$max,
        'end'=>$dt->format('Y-m-d ').$min
    ];
    foreach($free as $k=>$f){
        if($m['start']>$f['start'] && $m['start']<=$f['end']){
            $free[$k]['end'] = $m['start'];
            if($m['end']<$f['end'])
                $free[] = ['start'=>$m['end'], 'end'=>$f['end']];
        }
        elseif($m['end']<$f['end'] && $m['end']>$f['start']){
            $free[$k]['start'] = $m['end'];
        }
    }
}
foreach($free as $k=>$f){
    $s = explode(" ",$f['start']);
    $e = explode(" ",$f['end']);
    if($s[0] == $e[0]){
        $daily_free[$s[0]][] = ['start_free'=>$s[1], 'end_free'=>$e[1]];
    }
}
ksort($daily_free);
print_r($daily_free);
```

Comment: Wow, tested and seems to work flawlessly! I'll award the correct answer to @guided1 as requested, but I'll create a bounty when allowed in 2 days and award you this! Thanks for going the extra mile...

Comment: Wow. Extra mile indeed!

Answer (score 1):

A pure MySQL solution. Not truly practical, but more like a brain exercise:

```
SELECT r.* 
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT dd.`day`, 
        IF(dd.`ba` = 1, f.`free_before_start`, f.`free_after_start`) as `start`,  
        IF(dd.`ba` = 1, f.`free_before_end`, f.`free_after_end`) as `end`
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            a.`day`,
            IF(ISNULL(a.`id`) OR a.`before_day` < a.`day`, a.`day_start`, a.`before_end`) as `free_before_start`, 
            IF(ISNULL(a.`id`), a.`day_end`, a.`start`) as `free_before_end`,
            IF(ISNULL(a.`id`), a.`day_start`, a.`end`) as `free_after_start`, 
            IF(ISNULL(a.`id`) OR a.`next_day` > a.`day`, a.`day_end`, a.`next_start`) as `free_after_end`
        FROM (
            SELECT n.*, 
            b.`day` as `before_day`, b.`end` as `before_end`,
            t.`day` as `next_day`, t.`start` as `next_start`
            FROM (
                SELECT (@c1 := @c1 + 1) as `rowid`, s.*
                FROM (
                    SELECT d.`day`, d.`start` AS `day_start`, d.`end` AS `day_end`, 
                            m.`id`, GREATEST(d.`start`, m.`start`) AS `start`, LEAST(d.`end`, m.`end`) AS `end`     
                    FROM days d
                    LEFT JOIN `meetings` m ON 
                            m.start <= d.end 
                        AND m.end >= d.start
                    ORDER BY  2 ASC, 6 ASC
                ) s
                CROSS JOIN (SELECT @c1 := 0) AS dummy
            ) n
            LEFT JOIN 
            (
                SELECT (@c2 := @c2 + 1) as `rowid`, s.*
                FROM (
                    SELECT d.`day`, d.`start` AS `day_start`, d.`end` AS `day_end`, 
                            m.`id`, GREATEST(d.`start`, m.`start`) AS `start`, LEAST(d.`end`, m.`end`) AS `end`     
                    FROM days d
                    LEFT JOIN `meetings` m ON 
                            m.start <= d.end 
                        AND m.end >= d.start
                    ORDER BY  2 ASC, 6 ASC
                ) s
                CROSS JOIN (SELECT @c2 := 0) AS dummy
            ) t on t.`rowid` = n.`rowid` + 1
            LEFT JOIN 
            (
                SELECT (@c3 := @c3 + 1) as `rowid`, s.*
                FROM (
                    SELECT d.`day`, d.`start` AS `day_start`, d.`end` AS `day_end`, 
                            m.`id`, GREATEST(d.`start`, m.`start`) AS `start`, LEAST(d.`end`, m.`end`) AS `end`     
                    FROM days d
                    LEFT JOIN `meetings` m ON 
                            m.start <= d.end 
                        AND m.end >= d.start
                    ORDER BY  2 ASC, 6 ASC
                ) s
                CROSS JOIN (SELECT @c3 := 0) AS dummy
            ) b on b.`rowid` = n.`rowid` - 1
        ) a
    ) f 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT `day`, 1 as `ba` FROM `days` 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT `day`, 2 as `ba` FROM `days` 
        ORDER BY 1, 2
    ) dd on f.`day` = dd.`day`
    WHERE f.`free_before_start` <> f.`free_before_end` OR f.`free_after_start` <> f.`free_after_end`
) r
WHERE r.`start` <> r.`end`
```

Requires a `working hours` table as following:

```
CREATE TABLE `days` (
  `day` date NOT NULL,
  `start` timestamp NOT NULL,
  `end` timestamp NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`day`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `days` 
    (`day`, `start`, `end`) 
VALUES 
    ('2016-11-06', '2016-11-06 07:00:00', '2016-11-06 17:00:00'),
    ('2016-11-07', '2016-11-07 07:00:00', '2016-11-07 17:00:00'),
    ('2016-11-08', '2016-11-08 07:00:00', '2016-11-08 17:00:00'),
    ('2016-11-09', '2016-11-09 07:00:00', '2016-11-09 17:00:00'),
    ('2016-11-10', '2016-11-10 07:00:00', '2016-11-10 17:00:00'), 
    etc, around 250 working days per year.
```

Adding date range all over the code can significantly speed it up, for short intervals, but make it even less readable.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than working with days and dates that you have, store the values as `DateTime` objects, then use these to convert the dates to UNIX time stamps.  These are simply an integer value of seconds since the start of the UNIX Epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00).

You can now do simple maths to find gaps within a singe day range (Convert start date/time and end date/time of day into time stamp for your end markers).

Once you have a start end block identified as a time stamp, you can then feed this back into a `DateTime` object and convert this back into a standard date representation.

Identifying the length of a free block is also quite simple.  As the values are all seconds, subtracting the start time from the end time will yield the number of seconds difference.  To ensure it is bigger than 15 minutes you can compare it against the integer value 900 (60 * 15), if it is larger then the gap is greater than 15 minutes.

Comment: I am not 100% sure how converting the dates to time stamps helps? I still need to some how for each day get the range between the end of one meeting and the start of the next? Does it matter if I do that in integers or actual date objects?

Comment: Convert to integers to simplify the dates, then end of one meeting becomes a number eg 1200, next meeting starts at 4500.  You can easily see there is a difference of 3300 seconds between end of one and start of next.  This is also greater than 15 minutes (900 seconds), so you now know you have a free block starting at 1200 and finishing at 4500.  Obviously those integers are not human friendly so when displaying the results back you'd need to convert back into regular dates.  (Values I have used are obviously not what you'd see for current dates :) )